# C++ Performacne analysis of tiled matrix multiplication with valgrind

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to figure out how to properly implement loop tiling. My code is based on http://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf . Theoretically I should get a performance gain by using the tiled matrix multiplication. But I don't necessarily. I will also present the results from valgrind's cachegrind, which are quite interesting I believe.

I commented out the different approaches.

```
// cpp program, matrix multiplication
// returns the elapsed time of the loop iterations measured by omp_get_wtime()

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>            // std::min
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // matrix dimensions
    const int row = 1000;
    const int col = 1000;

    // matrix stored as an array of size 1000*1000
    // temp will be b transposed, recommendation from the article mentioned above
    // res is of double precision, I ran into errors displaying the data when using a different data type
    int *a = new int[row*col];
    int *b = new int[row*col];
    int *temp = new int[row*col];
    double *res = new double[row*col];

    // initialization
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            a[i*col+j] = i*col+j;
            b[i*col+j] = i*col+j;
        }
    }

    // transposition of b
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            temp[i*col+j] = b[j*col+i];
        }
    }


    int i,j,k,x,y,z;

// "naive" matrix multiplication
    // double start = omp_get_wtime();
    // for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    //     for (j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
    //         for (k = 0; k < row; ++k) {
    //             res[ i * col + j ] +=  a[ i * col + k ] * b[ k * col + j ];      
    //         }
    //     } 
    // }
    // double end = omp_get_wtime();
    // std::cout << end-start << std::endl;



// "transposed" matrix multiplication
        // for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
           //  for (j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
                // for (k = 0; k < row; ++k) {
                   // res[ i * col + j ] +=  a[ i * col + k ] * temp[ k  + j * col  ];      
                // }
            // } 
        // }

// tiled (parallel) matrix multiplication
// from /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0
// cat coherency_line_size returns 64;
// thus I will use 64 as the blocking size;

    int incr = 64;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i += incr) {
         for (j = 0; j < col; j += incr) {
             res[i*col+j] = 0.0;
             for (k = 0; k < row; k += incr) {
                 for (x = i; x < std::min( i + incr, row ); x++) {
                     for (y = j; y < std::min( j + incr, col ); y++) {
                         for (z = k; z < std::min( k + incr, row ); z++) {

                             res[ x * col + y ] +=  a[ x * col + z ] * b[ z * col  + y  ];

                         }
                     } 
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

**Results:**

Now I present the results from compiling the three approaches on an Linux machine with an Intel Dual Core and 4Gb DRAM. First I will present the results from compiling without optimizations followed by the results of the compilation with optimizations. For each result the respective valgrinds cachegrind result will be added. For those unfamiliar with the software: From http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html

> "*Cache accesses for instruction fetches are summarised first, giving
>   the number of fetches made (this is the number of instructions
>   executed, which can be useful to know in its own right), the number of
>   I1 misses, and the number of LL instruction (LLi) misses.*"

**"naive" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel

16.5305    

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./parallel

==12558== I   refs:      39,054,659,801
==12558== I1  misses:             1,758
==12558== LLi misses:             1,738
==12558== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==12558== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==12558== 
==12558== D   refs:      20,028,690,508  (18,024,512,540 rd   + 2,004,177,968 wr)
==12558== D1  misses:     1,064,759,236  ( 1,064,571,085 rd   +       188,151 wr)
==12558== LLd misses:        62,877,799  (    62,689,774 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==12558== D1  miss rate:            5.3% (           5.9%     +           0.0%  )
==12558== LLd miss rate:            0.3% (           0.3%     +           0.0%  )
==12558== 
==12558== LL refs:        1,064,760,994  ( 1,064,572,843 rd   +       188,151 wr)
==12558== LL misses:         62,879,537  (    62,691,512 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==12558== LL miss rate:             0.1% (           0.1%     +           0.0%  )
```

**"transposed" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel

9.40104 

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./parallel

==13319== I   refs:      39,054,659,804
==13319== I1  misses:             1,759
==13319== LLi misses:             1,739
==13319== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==13319== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==13319== 
==13319== D   refs:      20,028,690,508  (18,024,512,539 rd   + 2,004,177,969 wr)
==13319== D1  misses:        63,823,736  (    63,635,585 rd   +       188,151 wr)
==13319== LLd misses:        62,877,799  (    62,689,774 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==13319== D1  miss rate:            0.3% (           0.3%     +           0.0%  )
==13319== LLd miss rate:            0.3% (           0.3%     +           0.0%  )
==13319== 
==13319== LL refs:           63,825,495  (    63,637,344 rd   +       188,151 wr)
==13319== LL misses:         62,879,538  (    62,691,513 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==13319== LL miss rate:             0.1% (           0.1%     +           0.0%  )
```

**"tiled" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel

13.4941 

==13872== I   refs:      62,967,276,691
==13872== I1  misses:             1,768
==13872== LLi misses:             1,747
==13872== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==13872== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==13872== 
==13872== D   refs:      35,593,733,973  (28,411,716,118 rd   + 7,182,017,855 wr)
==13872== D1  misses:         6,724,892  (     6,536,740 rd   +       188,152 wr)
==13872== LLd misses:         1,377,799  (     1,189,774 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==13872== D1  miss rate:            0.0% (           0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==13872== LLd miss rate:            0.0% (           0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==13872== 
==13872== LL refs:            6,726,660  (     6,538,508 rd   +       188,152 wr)
==13872== LL misses:          1,379,546  (     1,191,521 rd   +       188,025 wr)
==13872== LL miss rate:             0.0% (           0.0%     +           0.0%  )
```

Note the refs. have gone up considerably.

**Optimized compilation:**

**"naive" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -O3 parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel

4.87246

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./parallel

==11227== I   refs:      9,021,661,364
==11227== I1  misses:            1,756
==11227== LLi misses:            1,734
==11227== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==11227== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==11227== 
==11227== D   refs:      4,008,681,781  (3,004,505,045 rd   + 1,004,176,736 wr)
==11227== D1  misses:    1,065,760,232  (1,064,572,078 rd   +     1,188,154 wr)
==11227== LLd misses:       62,877,794  (   62,689,768 rd   +       188,026 wr)
==11227== D1  miss rate:          26.5% (         35.4%     +           0.1%  )
==11227== LLd miss rate:           1.5% (          2.0%     +           0.0%  )
==11227== 
==11227== LL refs:       1,065,761,988  (1,064,573,834 rd   +     1,188,154 wr)
==11227== LL misses:        62,879,528  (   62,691,502 rd   +       188,026 wr)
==11227== LL miss rate:            0.4% (          0.5%     +           0.0%  )
```

**"transposed" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -O3 parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel 

2.02121 

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./parallel

==12076== I   refs:      8,020,662,317
==12076== I1  misses:            1,753
==12076== LLi misses:            1,731
==12076== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==12076== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==12076== 
==12076== D   refs:      4,006,682,757  (3,002,508,030 rd   + 1,004,174,727 wr)
==12076== D1  misses:       63,823,733  (   63,635,579 rd   +       188,154 wr)
==12076== LLd misses:       62,877,795  (   62,689,769 rd   +       188,026 wr)
==12076== D1  miss rate:           1.5% (          2.1%     +           0.0%  )
==12076== LLd miss rate:           1.5% (          2.0%     +           0.0%  )
==12076== 
==12076== LL refs:          63,825,486  (   63,637,332 rd   +       188,154 wr)
==12076== LL misses:        62,879,526  (   62,691,500 rd   +       188,026 wr)
==12076== LL miss rate:            0.5% (          0.5%     +           0.0%  )
```

**"tiled" approach:**

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -O3 parallel -o parallel.cpp
$ ./parallel 

1.78285   

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./parallel

==14365== I   refs:      8,192,794,606
==14365== I1  misses:            1,753
==14365== LLi misses:            1,732
==14365== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==14365== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==14365== 
==14365== D   refs:      4,102,512,450  (3,083,324,326 rd   + 1,019,188,124 wr)
==14365== D1  misses:        6,597,429  (    6,409,277 rd   +       188,152 wr)
==14365== LLd misses:        1,377,797  (    1,189,770 rd   +       188,027 wr)
==14365== D1  miss rate:           0.1% (          0.2%     +           0.0%  )
==14365== LLd miss rate:           0.0% (          0.0%     +           0.0%  )
==14365== 
==14365== LL refs:           6,599,182  (    6,411,030 rd   +       188,152 wr)
==14365== LL misses:         1,379,529  (    1,191,502 rd   +       188,027 wr)
==14365== LL miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%     +           0.0%  )
```

My question is: why does the non-optimized "tiled" approach perform relatively worse then the optimized? Is there something wrong with my implementation of the tiling algorithm?

I mean it's obviously that while the cache-misses of the two approaches are approx. the same, the refs. (number of fetches made) have gone down from  60 bio+ to 8 bio. Hence there is no surprise that it's the faster now. But what is not obvious to me is where those additional 20 bio+ instructions come from? It should be the fastest implementation among those three not-optimized implementations, right?

Well, thank you many times.

BW

Vincent

Comment: Your code is timing the amount of time it takes to do the allocations `new[]` and it doesn't time how long it takes to do the deallocations, whcih you do not do, thus it leaks memory.  Time it using arrays and not dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you Paul for comment. I will need to conduct some more testing today on the static vs. dynamic array. I will post my results or in case a follow up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tiled approach is more complex codewise, and because of that has extra overhead. With optimized code of course this isn't much of a problem as the matrix is big enough to yield more benefits with the proper cache usage.

Now look at the unoptimized code:

```
                     for (z = k; z < std::min( k + incr, row ); z++) {
                                     -------------------------
```

These calculations will be executed in a tight loop. That's a perfect performance killer.

Moving them to an outer scope (e.g.: as soon as `k` is available) makes a big difference. Of course the optimizer can do this, but only if you ask it to opitmize it. That's why *it's usually worthless to measure unoptimized code*.

```
0m16.186s  "tiled" approach
0m11.543s  "tiled" approach with the hand optimization
0m10.919s  "transposed" approach
```

This is what I measured on my machine. Looks good enough to me.

Comment: Thank you Karoly for your comment. Can you specify the order of the loops that helped you get that speed-up?

Comment: All I did was moving the `std::min`s to the most outer scopes possible (creating a variable for each). you could do even better with hand optimization, but what's the point? :)

Comment: Good point; I think that understanding the "naked" code gives me a better understanding of what's going on. The compiler optimizations are a bit of a black box to me. So before using these tools I intend to understand the basic computation first.

Comment: Alright new results: I increased the size to 5000*5000; My expectation was that the (optimized) tiled version should perform better with increasing size. But it does not it's 2 times slower (~ 10 minutes) then the transposed version. I guess I still have some work to do =)